# How to detect the height and weight of a line from an image?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library, opencv

I have this image.
[image]

My goal is identify the length of the cracked line.
[image]

I performed the BNW image conversion from this image. The result is like this:
[image]

Now I need the help to measure the height and width of this line.

If anyone can kindly help me with this, it would be a great help.

Thanks in Advance.

for BNW conversion, I have used the following codes:

```
import cv2
im_gray = cv2.imread('1.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)


(thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

thresh = 127
im_bw = cv2.threshold(im_gray, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
```

Comment: use something  about shape detection and extract min a max height and width of the shape, dont know how to get the shape, google it : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-detect-shapes-in-images-in-python-using-opencv/

Comment: lowpass this (or median-filter) to remove the texture's influence. you only care about that crack, right?